# "frequency" of fields for which the p-adic regulator vanishes (mod p)

Tags: number-fields, p-adic

There is a very nice question which arises in the study of the
Discrete Logarithm Problem which I wish to present here.
The question, in a general setting, is to specify an empirical
expression for the "frequency" of fields for which the $p$-adic regulator
vanishes $(\bmod p)$.
More specifically: If $k$ is a number field and $p$ an odd prime, we let

$$R_{p}(k) \in \operatorname{Rems} :=\{0, 1, ..., p-1\}$$

be the remainder of the p-adic regulator modulo $p$.

One would expect that the values of $R_{p}(k)$ are uniformly distributed
within $\operatorname{Rems}$.

I would not expect the proof of such a statement to be within reach with
presently known techniques. However, there are some questions concerning
the way to even state the uniform distribution.

I think of two possible variants for this:

1. Arrange the number fields according to some "measure" that may
   depend on the degree and the discriminant, or only one of these parameters.

Therefore $\|k\| = \operatorname{disc}(k)$ and one takes averages either over
all fields or over all fields of fixed degree. Let then

$$N_B = \{ \text{number fields}\ k : \| k \| < B\ \text{and}\ R_{p}(k) = 0 \},$$

while

$$F_B = \{ \text{number fields}\ k : \| k \| < B \}.$$

$N_B(d)$ and $F_B(d)$ are defined similarly, restricting only
to fields of degree $d$.

The first conjectures: Fix $p$. Then
$$
\text{Conjecture 1:}\quad
\lim_{B\rightarrow +\infty} N_B/F_B = 1/p.
$$
$$
\text{Conjecture 2:}\quad
\lim_{B\rightarrow +\infty} N_B(d)/F_B(d) = 1/p.
$$

2. The second approach fixes $k$ and lets $p$ vary.
   Let $P \subset N$ be the set of all natural primes, then let
   $$\chi(p) = \begin{cases}
   0&\text{if}\ R_{p}(k) > 0,\\
   1&\text{if}\ R_{p}(k) = 0.\\
   \end{cases}
   $$

Then the conjectures state:
$$
\text{Conjecture 3:}\quad
\lim_{B\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{ p \in P, p < B} \chi(p) p  }{B/\log(B)} = 1.
$$
$$
\text{Conjecture 4:}\quad
\lim_{B\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{ p \in P, p < B} \chi(p)   }{\log \log B} = 1
$$

QUESTIONS:

a) Are analogous statements about uniform distribution of, say, the class
number modulo $p$ or some other field invariants already discussed in the
literature? And if yes, how does one express the uniform distributions?

b) Are any secondary phenomena, that may give raise to some constants in
the above conjectures, especially in Conjectures 3 and 4? I have in mind things like
the correction factors in the Hardy-Littlewood Conjecture
or other similar ones.

c) Do there exist some alternative ways for stating uniform distribution?

Comment: Your formulas would be easier to read if you used MathJax (which is essentially LaTeX) for formatting. There is a good guide here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/166535

Comment: A couple of things. First, no need to put the words "Research level" in the title of your post. Readers will judge whether the post is at the right level for this site. Second, MathOverflow uses basic LaTeX formatting. If you know LaTeX, please edit your post so that it's more readable. If not, post a comment asking for help and maybe someone will format it for you. But it really is worthwhile, if you're going to do math or crypto, to learn basic LaTeX.

Comment: I hope people were not downvoting this simply because of tex.

Comment: Let us leave it open for now and let the author do the edits.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that MathOverflow uses basic Latex, which I was not aware of since this is my first post here. I edited the post using Latex.

Comment: Much better readability. I'm going to do some further edits to make it even more readable. In particular, it often helps to display equations, rather than put them in-line. But formatting aside, these seem like interesting questions/conjectures. There's been a lot of amazing work in the past few years on various sorts of arithmetic averages by Bhargava and others. Possibly his techniques could give some results along these lines.

Comment: Please indicate a good reference linking the discrete log problem to $p$-adic regulators. Didn't know about that. Unless I'm forgetting something, the $p$-adic regulator is only known to be well-defined for special number fields, e.g., totally real number fields, so do you have in mind *all* number fields or just some special types of number fields? Does your counting of number fields include each number field once up to isomorphism, or are you counting number fields inside an algebraic closure of $\mathbf Q$ (then a field of degree $d$ occurs $d$ times)? Finally, why do you avoid $p = 2$?

Answer (score 1):

Some "equidistributions $\mod{p}$" are discussed in Washington's "Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields". I adress here only your first question, and have nothing to say about questions b) and c).

The first equidistribution is about irregular primes, and is discussed after Theorem 5.17 (I refer, here and henceforth, to the second edition), on page 62-63. The idea is to assume that the classes of Bernoulli numbers are random $\mod{p}$, in the sense that the probability that $p\mid B_j$ for some $j\in[2,4,6,\dots,p-3]$ is $1/p$. In this case one coops with a Poisson distribution and the deduced heuristic is that approximately $60\%$ of primes are regular, which agrees with computations.

A second distribution argument is briefly touched upon after Theorem 5.37 and concerns the possibility that the Bernoulli number $B_{(p-1)/2}$ be random $\mod{p}$. This would have consequences on the residue $\mod{p}$ of the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$: as it is explained in Exercice 5.9, though, one can show that $B_{(p+1)/2}$ is *not random* $\mod{p}$, as a consequence of Brauer-Siegel (at least for $p\equiv 3\pmod{4})$.

A third one concerns Vandiver's conjecture and is discussed in the Remark on page 158 ($\S$ 8.4). It shows that the naive approach of assuming that the $i$-th cyclotomic unit be a $p$-th power with probability $1/p$ fails dramatically, while there is a more refined example that combines the above assumption with the needed hypothesis that $p$ be irregular; the very first heuristics I mentioned, about equidistribution of the $j$-th Bernoulli number $B_j\pmod{p}$, implies that possible exceptions to Vandiver's up to $p\leq x$ go like $1/2\log\log(x)$, and is therefore of no significance that we haven't found any counterexample so far. The very same section of Washington's book has a final remark on Vandiver based on the equidistribution assumption that $p\mid h^+$ with probability $1/p$ (where $h^+$ is the class number of the totally real field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p+\zeta_p^{-1})$). In this case again, Vandiver could be false for a prime $p\leq x$ with probability
$$
\log\log(x)
$$
which is bigger than before but roughly analogous. In both cases, since computations (at the time of Washingtons' writing, namely 1996) can go up to $p\sim 4.000.000$ and $\log\log(4.000.000)=2.72...$, that no exception has been found is "not *too* strange".

I should perhaps add that it seems that P. Mihailescu has some argument for turning Washington's heuristic "in favor" of Vandiver [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.6283/%22here%22).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. While
Bernoulli numbers have a heuristic distribution which is confirmed by
intensive computations, in our case numeric evidence is scarce.